Are soldiers sinning when they kill enemy in a war?
Soldiers are like slaves to their commanders and have to do whatever they are told to do. If not, in war like situation, they can be punished by their commanders. So will the soldiers be accountable for the killing they do ?
The question came to mind because of the recent war in Palestine. The jews who are fighting Palestinians are doing so because they have to do compulsory military service, so even if they dislike killing people, they are compelled to do so.
Note: I have asked same question in Judaism section also. Actually Muslims and Jews are brothers who are descended of our patriarch Abraham (Peace be upon him), It is sad to see them fighting each other, I feel like they are forced to fight each other by some who have vested interest in this conflict.

Soldiers are not sinning when they kill an enemy in a war, regardless of whether they do it willingly or under orders, because killing is permissible in war.

فاقتلوا المشركين حيث وجدتموهم
then kill the polytheists wherever you find them
— Quran 9:5


واقتلوهم حيث ثقفتموهم
And kill them wherever you overtake them
— Quran 2:191


فإذا لقيتم الذين كفروا فضرب الرقاب
So when you meet those who disbelieve [in battle], strike [their] necks
— Quran 47:4

However if you mean killing someone whose blood is not lawful (e.g. an enemy who has accepted Islam and surrendered) then killing such a person is forbidden and sinful. There is no excuse of following orders as there is no obedience to a commander if that involves disobedience to Allah:

أن النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم بعث جيشا وأمر عليهم رجلا، فأوقد نارا وقال ادخلوها‏.‏ فأرادوا أن يدخلوها، وقال آخرون إنما فررنا منها، فذكروا للنبي صلى الله عليه وسلم فقال للذين أرادوا أن يدخلوها ‏لو دخلوها لم يزالوا فيها إلى يوم القيامة ‏وقال للآخرين لا طاعة في معصية، إنما الطاعة في المعروف
The Prophet (ﷺ) , sent an army and appointed some man their commander The man made a fire and then said (to the soldiers), "Enter it." Some of them intended to enter it while some others said, 'We have run away from it (i.e., embraced Islam to save ourselves from the 'fire')." They mentioned that to the Prophet, and he said about people who had intended to enter the fire. ''If they had entered it, they would have remained In it till the Day of Resurrection.' Then he said to others, "No obedience for evil deeds, obedience is required only in what is good ."
— Bukhari


السمع والطاعة حق، ما لم يؤمر بالمعصية، فإذا أمر بمعصية فلا سمع ولا طاعة
It is obligatory for one to listen to and obey (the ruler's orders) unless these orders involve disobedience (to Allah); but if an act of disobedience (to Allah) is ordered, he should not listen to or obey it.
— Bukhari

